# Exporting records with more than 250 characters in a field to GML

Tags: gdal, openstreetmap, grass-gis, ogr2ogr, ogr

I am trying to export OSM vectors to the `GML` format like:

```
v.out.ogr input=network output=network.gml format=GML
```

I get an error that the field `a_other_tags` has more than 250 characters:

> ERROR 1: Field a_other_tags has a 255 UTF-8 characters whereas a maximum of 250 is allowed
> ERROR: Failed to create OGR feature

If I export to GPKG, I get a similar warning but all the records appear to be exported. However, when I try to convert from GPKG to GML with `ogr2ogr` the offending records are dropped:

```
ogr2ogr -skipfailures -f GML network.gml network.gpkg
```

> ERROR 1: Field a_other_tags has a 255 UTF-8 characters whereas a maximum of 250 is allowed

Is there a way to just truncate the field when exporting using `v.out.ogr` or when using `ogr2ogr`?

Comment: Can you confirm in the GPKG that the records are not exported? It could just be a warning like here - https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/25405

Comment: OK, so if I import the exported GPKG it does have the correct number of records. I will rephrase my question now, thanks!

Comment: Just as an information: `ERROR 1` is coming from GDAL/OGR error (it isn't a GRASS GIS error) as `v.out.ogr` depends on OGR.

Comment: Thanks Markus! I kind of figured that since the error is the same using ogr2ogr as the GRASS module. Do you know of a dataset creation option to truncate the field? Or can you recommend a way to truncate it before exporting?

Comment: This is the line that writes the error https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/2cfeb1a9b03716c8348d6f1f4c611f2589d53e76/ogr/ogrfeature.cpp#L7064 but I wonder where the maximum field length gets set into 250. A small test dataset that could be used for re-producing the error would be good.

Comment: Try with `-lco PRECISION=NO` . Description PRECISION=[YES/NO]: Defaults to YES. This may be "YES" to force new fields created on this layer to try and represent the width of text fields (in terms of UTF-8 characters, not bytes), if available using TEXT(width) types. If "NO" then the type TEXT will be used instead.

Comment: Sorry, the previous option is for the GPKG driver, not for GML.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried that but yeah, got the error “does not support layer creation option PRECISION”. This should reproduce the issue: http://3dtopo.com/vector_3857.tar.gz Just let me know if you have any questions.